# What is the difference and which one is well expression between these sentences?

Tags: expressions

I am curious to Know the best one from these sentences.

> 1. I found the following sentence on the Internet
> 2. I've got a some sentence when I ran across on a web

Would you let me know that does the 2nd sentence weird?
Also which one is well expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second sentence is incorrect. The first sentence is correct.

'I've got some' implies that you have more than one sentence. I think what you mean by 'I ran across' is 'I came across'. 'On a web' would mean, for example a spider's web. If you meant the internet, you say 'the web'. So I would change that sentence to: 'I've got a sentence that I came across on the web.'

Answer (score 0):

The first one is correct but the second one is not correct. In the second sentence the word 'a' implies that you have found one sentence when you searched on the internet but the words 'some sentences' implies that you have found more than one sentence when you searched on the internet. Therefore the first one is well expressed.